# Как работает str.indexOf?

Tags: javascript

Изучаю javascript. В учебнике вот такой пример:

```
var str = "Widget with id";

alert( str.indexOf("Widget") ); // 0, т.к. "Widget" найден прямо в начале str
alert( str.indexOf("id") ); // 1, т.к. "id" найден, начиная с позиции 1
alert( str.indexOf("widget") ); // -1, не найдено, так как поиск учитывает регистр
```

Почему во 2 случае `1` а не `2`? Это ведь 3 элемент

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Поиск идет по строке, значит по всем символам: W**id**get - "нашлось" **id** в слове Widget.

```
W i d g et with id
0 1 2 3 ...

// разделите строку на символы и увидите сами
"Widget with id".split('')
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут как и в массивах, всё начинается с 0, так и первый символ всегда нулевой.
Второй пример id нашёл, начиная с первого индекса, значит и выдал 1.